# Search pdf page based on <div> tag contents

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf

Currently I am using `<A HREF="http://www.example.com/myfile.pdf#page=4">`. Is there any way to search for a PDF section based on `<div>` content and not the page number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PDF's don't have <div> elements, so there's no way to search for them.

Although the URL address implies your example file is a PDF, if you look at its source code, you can see that it's just a plain HTML file.